# Why passing args from powershell gives error while working from inside script itself

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Why calling `.\MyScript.ps1 -Uninstall` from Powershell gives an error

```
+ Super-Function $Args
+                ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData : (:) [Super-Function], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Super-Function
```

While calling "Super-Function" from the script itself with `Super-Function -Uninstall` , replacing $Args with the switch works ?
Why copy pasting the function on Powershell and then going for `Super-Function -Uninstall` works too ?

Here's the content of MyScript.ps1

```
function Super-Function([parameter(Mandatory=$False)][ValidateScript({Test-Path _$})][String]$var1 = ".\MyFile.ext",
                        [parameter(Mandatory=$False)][ValidateScript({Test-Path _$})][String]$var2 = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Publisher\SoftwareName",
                        [parameter(Mandatory=$False)][ValidateScript({([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")})][Switch]$Uninstall,
                        [parameter(Mandatory=$False)][ValidateScript({([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")})][Switch]$Install
                        )
{
}



Super-Function $Args
```

Comment: So you expect `$args` to work against the function inside the script then? Might just have to use `@args` but im tired and dont know for sure.

Comment: Looks like I was more tired than expected, thanks. Please hit me as hard as you can in an answer to allow me to mark it as solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few issues there that I see. Your `ValidateScript` for each argument have an issue. First, might just be a typo, you have the characters backwards for current pipe item. Should be `$_` instead of `_$`. Next I find it befuddling that you test the presence of the admin role against a couple of boolean switches. Lets just move that inside the function (If what you had works that is fine. Just does make much sense)

Lastly, and most importantly, what you are trying to do with `$args` is called splatting. Use `@args` which will splat the hashtable of arguments, passed in from the script, against the function.

```
function Super-Function{

    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$False)][ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})][String]$var1 = ".\MyFile.ext",
        [parameter(Mandatory=$False)][ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})][String]$var2 = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Publisher\SoftwareName",
        [parameter(Mandatory=$False)][Switch]$Uninstall,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$False)][Switch]$Install
    )

    # Use this to verify what has been assinged to your parameters. Will not show default values. 
    #$PSBoundParameters

    If(([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")){
        "Sure"
    } Else {
        Throw "Nope"
    }
}

Super-Function @args
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, the only purpose of this function is to call other functions based on arguments, obviously the "function launcher" shouldn't stop if the user isn't in admin group, the function only checks if uninstall/install is true or not to start said function, checking if the user is admin at parameter level seemed good to me, moving it to the function part would still require me to put it two time, or use other conditional stuff. Knowing this, is it still best to move that verification ?

Comment: Typically ValidateScript is a means to verify that the parameter passed is of a certain value. So you passing an uninstall switch and checking for admin rights does not make sense.